# JDBC Connection: access denied

Tags: mysql, ssl, jdbc

I am trying to get the JDBC connection with mysql over SSL.
I have already imported the valid certificate to cacertsSSL.jks file.
Still i am not able to connect.

Is there a way out without extending or changing the Driver?

```
public static void getMysqlConnection() {
    Connection connection = null;
    try {

      Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
      Driver driver = DriverManager.getDriver(URL);
      DriverPropertyInfo[] info = driver.getPropertyInfo(URL, null);

      String URL = "jdbc:mysql://myHost:3307/myDB?verifyServerCertificate=false&amp;requireSSL=true&amp;useSSL=true";
      String USER = "myUser";
      String PASSWORD = "myPwd";

      System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", "C:\\Development\\cacertsSSL.jks");
      System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", "changeit");
      System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "C:\\Development\\cacertsSSL.jks");
      System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "changeit");

      Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, USER, PASSWORD);
      System.out.println(conn);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      System.out.println("Connection Failed! Check output console");
      e.printStackTrace();
      return;
    }
  }
```

Below is connection error Stack Trace

```
java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'myuser'@'myHost' (using password: YES)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1055)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:956)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3491)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3423)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:910)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.secureAuth411(MysqlIO.java:3923)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1273)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2031)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:718)
at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:46)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:406)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:302)
at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:282)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:582)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:154)
at com.test.Test1.getMysqlConnection(Test1.java:152)
at com.test.Test1.main(Test1.java:25)
```

Answer:
 Here is what made it work:

```
  String URL = "jdbc:mysql://myHost:3307/myDB?useSSL=true";
  String USER = "myUser";
  String PASSWORD = "myPwd";

  System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "C:\\Development\\cacertsSSL.jks");
  System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "changeit");
```

Only TrustStore is sufficient in this case and only useSSL worked in my case.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You got the username or password wrong, or you can't connect as that user from that host. But that also indicates that the SSL part is working properly.

Comment: Yes on the DB side this user is expected to connect over SSL and valid certificate. When i use this user & pwd in Toad providing the valid certificate, the user is able to connect. But with the program above in the question, it does not work ! Any Idea?

Comment: The stack trace says that access was denied 'using password'. If it was a certificate/SSL problem it would have said something quite different. I don't think you have MySQL configured the way you think.